# Is it possible to convert a hex string to mongodb object Id during aggregation query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I want to convert a hex string to mongodb ObjectId before project that field.

I have tried this:

Data in products document :

`{
    _id : ObjectId("571b73c2b190ecdc598b4567")
    categories : [
        "571b73c2b190evdc598bad67",
        "571b73c2b1c0evdc598cad67"
    ]
}`

```js
  db.products.aggregate([
    { $match : { _id : ObjectId("571b73c2b190ecdc598b4567") } },
    { $unwind : '$categories' },    
    { $project : { 'category_id' : ObjectId("$categories") } },
    { $lookup : { from : 'categories', localField: 'categories', foreignField : '_id', as : 'categoriesData' } }
]).pretty()
```

But it returns an error:

> Error: invalid object id: length

Comment: I have added a little more markdown to make your question more readable.
Can you [edit] your question further - for example it would be useful to know what kind of data is in `categories`? And what are you expecting `ObjectId("$categories")` to do exactly?

Comment: categories contain an array of category id but in string format and mongo dosen't match hex string with object id.

Comment: Hi Divergent - when you clarify your answer, you need to do it in an [edit] to your question, not just as a comment.

Comment: I have found that there is no way to do this mongo community is working on it. https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-22781